# Calculating the running time of Quicksort's PARTITION procedure

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, quicksort

I am confused about calculating the PARTITION procedure's running time.

PARTITION procedure is used in the Quicksort Algorithm to partition the array $A[p...r]$

I analyzed the PARTITION procedure provided in the book Introduction to Algorithms:

```
  PARTITION(A, p, r)
1.  x= A[r]
2.  i= p-1
3.  for(j = p to r-1)
4.       if(A[j]<= x)
5.         i= i+1
6.         exchange A[i] with A[j]
7.  exchange A[i+1] with A[r]
8.  return i+1
```

Now what I figured out that:

1. Every procedure except lines $3-6$ has a constant time i.e: $\Theta(1)$
2. For loop would execute $r-1-p+1$ times.

Thus the running time should be: $\Theta(r-p)$

While the book quotes:

> The running time of PARTITION on the subarray $A[p...r]$ is $\Theta(n)$ where $n= r-p+1$.

Could someone please help me out in knowing how to prove the aforementioned complexity?

Thank you.

Comment: note that though the body of the loop runs $r-p$ times the condition that $j\leq r-1$  runs for $r-p+1$ times, To be more precise, after $r-p$ iterations of the loop body, the loop control moves to the condition check portion of the loop and checks that the condition is no longer valid, so this accounts for the extra $1$ which you point out, Moreover in asymptotic analysis, a variable (here $n$) added or subtracted by a constant does not affect the $\Theta$ bound. Simply because $a_k.n^k+a_{k-1}.n^{k-1}+...+a_0 \in \Theta(n^k)$. So even if $f(n)=n-1$, i.e.($f(n)=r-p$) $f(n)\in \Theta(n)$.

Comment: The loop body accounts for $r-p$ times and the loop header for $r-p+1$ times. This is quite clear to me but the only problem was getting it close to $n$. So my evaluation was right and we can no way prove it exactly equal to $n$ is it?

Comment: Yes you are right.Though the loop body runs for only $n-1$ times, but there are other lines in the algorithm as well. analysis might account for them as well, (though the constants does not matter here, it is secondary)

Comment: But won't that be $\Theta(n-1)+ \Theta(1)$  where $\Theta(1)$ accounts for swapping the $A[i+1]$ with $A[r]$.

Comment: a proper detailed analysis should include a detailed analysis of each line of the code (as done in the 1st chapter of CLRS) but a rough quite obvious analysis ignores certain constants as they do not affect the dominant terms in $\Theta$ analysis.

Comment: Yes I wrote $\Theta(1)$ to signify all the other constant time taking lines.

Comment: so you answered your question now

Comment: Well but won't that still be choosing $\Theta(n-1)$ over $\Theta(1)$?

Comment: But the result shall be same if you think in that way as $\Theta(n-1)=\Theta(n)$ as constants does not matter in $\Theta$ analysis

Comment: Okay. I got it.